# Dynamic array of ints or not?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

If I create a struct in one class as so

```
typedef struct
{     
    int numberOfTiles;
    // an array of ints here
    int *tileArray; 

} CollisionLayer;
```

is it possible to create an array of ints with an empty [] and set the size on creation? Or how would this array be created? dynamically with a pointer? I will know the size of the array when creating one of these struct "objects", if it is possible to fill in the size of the array on creation, how is the array declared in the struct above?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to initialize the array yourself:

```
CollisionLayer layer;
layer.numberOfTiles = numberOfTiles;
layer.tileArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfTiles);
```

Or, if you want to create the struct on the heap:

```
CollisionLayer* pl  = (CollisionLayer*)malloc(sizeof(CollisionLayer));
pl->numberOfTiles = numberOfTiles;
pl->tileArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numberOfTiles);

// When you are done:
free(pl->tileArray);
free(pl);
```

The other option would be to hardcode a fixed size limit into `CollisionLayer`, e.g.:

```
typedef struct
{     
    int numberOfTiles;
    // an array of ints here
    int tileArray[100]; 

} CollisionLayer;
```

Of course this will be less desirable in all respects, but it's your only option if you don't want to manage memory manually.

Comment: Im confused when it comes to malloc of structs that themselves have items which need to be malloced. Would the CollisionLayer layer need to be malloced?

Comment: @Helium3: It would need to be *only if you want to fully control its lifetime* (because a local goes out of scope when it does, not when you want it to, etc). This is a different reason than the one that makes you `malloc` the array: you don't know how large it's going to be at compile time.

Comment: I definitely want to manage memory manually. So if I want this collisionLayer to have a life, creating the pointer is correct? how does the creation of this occur? Malloc the struct and then malloc the array?

Comment: @Helium3: Yes. I 've updated the answer to show how -- it's what you said, basically.

Comment: @Jon: Great, thanks :) I dont know why the jump from obj c to C is more difficult than I thought. Another thing, if my code is executing and the scheduler, for some reason moves control to another task, will creating objects in either way be effected(on the heap or on the stack)? For example, if a pointer is created and the scheduler kills/intervenes the process, can the pointed to memory be lost?

Comment: @Helium3: No, you can enjoy single-threaded bliss until the moment you eat from the tree of threads ;)

Comment: @Jon: I have working with multithreading in obj c and erlang(untraceable (at my skill level)data race bugs till my brain exploded). The thing is, we are working on an embedded project at uni and one of the groups is writing the scheduler.A round robin based one. I was wondering with regards to this? Im sure it depends on how they implement it, but is this situation likely?

Comment: It depends on your memory allocator. The simplest case is to have a memory allocator which serializes all memory allocations and the critical sections of the allocator need to be protected (hint mutexes). Apparently this will impact on performance in scenarios with lots of memory allocations on lots of threads. Summary: it's not a question of the process scheduler but a question of how well the memory allocator is written and how good the implementation of the synchronization primitives is (assuming this is a student OS project)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the size at compile time, then you must allocate the memory  using malloc() at runtime. To use an actual array in C, you must know the size when the code is compiled.

Answer (score 1):

tileArray is a pointer to int.  malloc/calloc should be used to create the object to which it will point to.  This should happen when creating an object of CollisionLayer.

Defining a struct in which the array [] is empty is not a good idea, refer [this](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=288).  It speaks of C++, bit it should apply for C as well.

Answer (score 1):

VLAs cannot be members of structs so you will need to allocate the memory with `malloc` when you create the struct object.